# FullCalendar not displaying correctly

Tags: json, fullcalendar

In IE it shows this: 
Mar 8 â€” 14, 2015 - â€ (incorrect)

In Firefox/chrome it shows correctly as this:
Jun 28 — Jul 4, 2015

I have changed this 

Also trying it with content="application/json

It still not show up correctly. Suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide more info? Is not displaying where? What is your code? Are you following the demo/manual?

Comment: In the header I have this (the calendar shows up fine using code from fullcalendar.io)   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<!--<!-- using this meta tags prevents â€ --><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />